# How do I make sure my Select Content GA4 event doesn't remove the type and ID values?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I'm trying to set up the `select_content` event [as laid out in the GA4 Recommended Events page.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#select_content)

However, my current organization wants to use the dataLayer syntax to push this event to GTM instead of gtag.js. The way I've set it up looks like this:

```
const dataLayerObjectToPush: {
    event: "select_content",
    content_type: "type_string",
    content_id: "id_string"
};

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push(dataLayerObjectToPush);
```

However, when I send it through to be processed through GTM, the `content_type` and `content_id` values get stripped. What's happening here, and how can I make sure those values don't get removed?

Comment: did you create the corresponding data layer variables in GTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I needed to set up the appropriate variables in Google Tag Manager, and link them to my `select_content` event.